# Check column values are in different sets

Tags: r

I have a data frame called `data` with lots of columns, and `Country` is one of them.

I created a new logical column called `train`, which is true when the row belongs to the train set and false otherwise.  The data frame is already sampled.

Now I want to be sure that there are no countries in both train and test sets with this code:

```
nrow( data[ data[ data$train, ]$Country %in% data[! data$train, ]$Country, ] ) == 0
```

which evaluates to `true`, so I guess I sampled correctly.  But that line makes my eyes bleed.

Comment: As `data` is also the name of a function in the core `utils` package, it is not good practice to use it for the name of an object.

Answer (score 2):

I would do:

```
with(data, length(intersect(Country[train], Country[!train])) == 0)
```